# android and php script

Tags: php, android

I am new to android. I want to call simple php script that echo some basic string, and i want to show that string inside textView in android application. but when i click my button for calling php script nothing happends. Here is my android code:

```
public void phpConnection(View v){
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    final ProgressDialog p = new       ProgressDialog(v.getContext()).show(v.getContext(),"Waiting for Server", "Accessing Server");
    //TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv); 
    //tv.setText("Response from PHP");
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             try{

                 httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                 httppost= new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/testic.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
                 //add your data
                 nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                 // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Edittext_value",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 //Execute HTTP Post Request
                 response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

                 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                 final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                 System.out.println("Response : " + response);
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            p.dismiss();
                            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv); 
                             tv.setText("Response from PHP" + response);
                        }
                    });

             }catch(Exception e){

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        p.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                 System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
             }
        }
    };

    thread.start();


}
```

and here is simple testic.php script:

```
<?php

$val="My name is Nedim";
echo $val;
}
?>
```

this script is saved in wamp server.
Please, can anyone tell me where is error.

Comment: I think _you_ need to tell _us_ where the error is, not the other way around. Does your logcat say anything? What have you done to try to debug this (other than seeing the button doesn't work and posting here)?

Comment: Try run http://127.0.0.1/testic.php in your mobile browser. If nothing appears, the reason is simple. The android device can't see the local server and its pages.

Answer (score 0):

look at the apache logs -> access.log | other_vhosts_access.log | error.log, if you see something is coming from your app ;) - or you shutdown your apache and run "netcat" like:

```
nc -vvlp80
```

after this you try to run your app, and you will see the http requests in the window